# Get data from two tables in SQL Server, on where condition of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Exercises` & `Workouts`. I want to fetch data from these two tables as follows:

Table structure (screenshot): table above is workout table & below that is exercises table.

[image]

I want result will be like (screenshot):

[image]

How can I get the above result from these two tables on where condition of `workout_name ='Testing'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `join` them

```
select w.workout_name, e.exercise_name, e.exercise_image 
from Workouts w
join Exercises e on e.exercise_name = w.exercise_name
where w.workout_name = 'Testing'
```

Answer (score -1):

We can also use cross apply for this-

```
SELECT w.workout_name, w.exercise_name, x.exercise_image 
FROM Workouts w
CROSS APPLY 
( 
    SELECT e.exercise_image FROM Exercises e WHERE e.exercise_name = w.exercise_name 
) x
WHERE w.workout_name = 'Testing'
```

Comment: Isn't this executing the subquery for every `Workout`?

Comment: CROSS APPLY is for joining tables to table valued functions.. this question should be done with a regular join

Comment: @caramiriel don't worry, sql server isn't that naive. The query you write and the query sql server runs will frequently be very different. Read up on what the query optimiser in an rsbms does :)

Comment: It takes care of where clause while creating the execution plan. So it will only executes the sub query for 'Testing' workout_name.

Comment: @CaiusJard Ah neat, I didn't expect it would do that with cross apply as well. Thanks for the info. (queryplan: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/987037/1)